# "Redefinition" of momentum in Schwinger's Classical Electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, classical-electrodynamics, textbook-erratum

I'm asking this question because I'm currently engaged in self-study of the book "Classical Electrodynamics" by J. Schwinger, *et al*. In particular I'm reading chapter 4, section 1, on the force on an atom whence one reaches the following equation (from a first order Taylor approximation about the center of mass of the charge distribution and the definition of the electric dipole moment $d$):

$\mathrm{F}=\nabla [\mathrm{d\cdot E(R})]-\frac{1}{c}(\mathrm{V}\cdot \nabla)\mathrm{d\times B(R})+\frac{1}{c}\frac{d}{dt}[\mathrm{d\times B(R)}]+\dots (4.10)$

Inmediately following this expression the author states "Recalling that force is the time rate of change of the momentum we see that $\frac{1}{c}\mathrm{d\times B}$ introduces a **redefinition of the momentum** of the system.".

My question is: *How is $\frac{1}{c}\mathrm{d\times B}$ a redefinition of the momentum?*

As far as I understand one can rearrange the last two terms of the force (using the notion of total/material derivative) as:

$-\frac{1}{c}(\mathrm{V}\cdot \nabla)[\mathrm{d\times B}]+\frac{1}{c}\frac{d}{dt}[\mathrm{d\times B}]=-\frac{1}{c}(\mathrm{V}\cdot \nabla)[\mathrm{d\times B}]+\frac{1}{c}(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\mathrm{V}\cdot \nabla)[\mathrm{d\times B}]=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{c}[\mathrm{d\times B}]$

And therefore the total force would be:

$\mathrm{F}=\nabla [\mathrm{d\cdot E}]+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{c}[\mathrm{d\times B}]$

But then the momentum would not be the originally claimed $\frac{1}{c}\mathrm{d\times B}$, but rather:

$\mathrm{p}=\int_0^t(\nabla [\mathrm{d\cdot E}]+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{c}[\mathrm{d\times B}])=\int_0^t(\nabla [\mathrm{d\cdot E}])+\frac{1}{c}[\mathrm{d\times B}]$

Which is clearly different unless the first term integrates to zero, but I don't see a clear way in which this would happen for any arbitrary $t$.

Can someone help me elucidate this matter?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm didn't know how to use **boldface** within the equations so I decided to use straightface instead for the vectors. I also apologize for the reduced size of the fractions and integrals, which I couldn't format quite as I wanted.

Comment: In a way this is an issue with notation/identification. In the regular balance of momentum in vacuum for electromagnetism, one usually splits three contributions that add to $0$: the change in mechanical momentum of the sources, the change in electromagnetic momentum and the (integrated over the volume) divergence of the Maxwell stress tensor. Here the splitting is probably similar in that the divergence term is not associated to the electromagnetic momentum but with a stress tensor contribution.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the case. This equations come from the Lorentz force equation on the charge distribution, not from the balance of momentum (which is detailed in chapter 3). The divergence term adds to 0 in a vacuum because you can make the volume integration into a surface one via Stokes' theorem. That is not the case here since the integration is in time. In fact, the final form of the force in this section of the book involves only the gradient term (with a similar form for the magnetic dipole moment with B) and the third term on the right of the equation I posted above.

Comment: First, both relations, the one in vacuum done in chapter 3 and the one you mention in chapter 4 are precisely about the balance of momentum, just in different contexts. Second, both have time dependent differentiation (if you write them as balance of forces) or time integration (if you attempt to compute the total change of momentum in an interval of time as the last equation of your question). Third, you can also either write them as (spatial) densities as in eq 3.15 or as integrated quantities, as in eqs 3.8 or 4.2. Fourth, I am aware of the final result as I have the book too.

Comment: Just like in eq 4.2, in eq 4.22 we have forces and not force densities. It is then natural to pick the only quantity being differentiated in time to be the momentum. The physical origin of this term is the coupling of the magnetic field with the currents produced by the motion of the charges, which is consistent with the intuition coming from the Lorentz force. We don't have an "electric" contribution because charge adds to $0$ in this case. As you mention, the other terms are gradients, of things that we can read as (minus) potential energies.

Comment: I think I'm getting it now. I hadn't thought about the other term as potential energy. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text only alludes to the possibility of redefining momentum of a macroscopic body and of macroscopic EM force. But it does not give any argument in favor of such a change of view.

The symbol $\mathbf F$ they use throughout the section refers to total EM force, equal to sum of all the elementary Lorentz forces due to external field. This, by the 2nd law of motion, is equal to time derivative of total mechanical momentum

$$
\mathbf P = \sum_a m_a\mathbf v_a
$$

(assuming non-relativistic mechanics). There is no redefinition going on, nor is it needed or useful in this context of derivation of 4.22.

What they mean by that redefinition is probably this. The formula 4.22 predicts that total EM force on the material system is 
$$
\mathbf F = \nabla \bigg(\mathbf d\cdot \mathbf E + \boldsymbol \mu \cdot \mathbf B\bigg) + \frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{1}{c}\mathbf d\times \mathbf B\bigg).
$$

If this is the only force acting on the body, we can rewrite this either as

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \bigg(\sum_a m_a\mathbf v_a\bigg) = \nabla \bigg(\mathbf d\cdot \mathbf E + \boldsymbol \mu \cdot \mathbf B\bigg) + \frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{1}{c}\mathbf d\times \mathbf B\bigg)
$$

or

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\sum_a m_a\mathbf v_a - \frac{1}{c}\mathbf d\times \mathbf B\bigg) = \nabla \bigg(\mathbf d\cdot \mathbf E + \boldsymbol \mu \cdot \mathbf B\bigg).
$$

The redefinition does not in any way follow from 4.22; it is a conscious decision of the physicist doing so; it is merely allowed by the fact that part of the EM force expression 4.22 is a total time derivative.
Of course, the purpose of this redefinition is not clear from that text.